# Caching some data in Magento

Tags: cache, performance, full-page-cache, menu, redis

I'm trying to cache my menu module like this:

```
$cache = Mage::app()->getCache();

if(!($cachedMenu = $cache->load("super_menu_".$child->getId())))
{
   ....blah blah blah .... generating some string ...

   $cache->save("super_menu_".$child->getId(),$str);
}
else
   echo $cachedMenu;
```

But It seems everytime it tries to generate the menu, I'm using Redis as my caching system and it works great for other parts of my codes. I don't know if I missed something here or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem in the order of your save attributes. I think it should be Value then cache key.

```
public function save($data, $id, $tags = array(), $lifeTime = null)
```

What I think you are doing is saving the string as the id and so your load does not find anything.

Some good notes on cache can be found here https://www.nicksays.co.uk/developers-guide-magento-cache/